# A big project on Apache Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming, apache-zeppelin

I have a streaming job that need to be launched through Zeppelin. However, it is very big project. As far as I know, the program launched on Zeppelin is notebook style, with several hundreds lines of code at most.

My code has several thousands of lines, with many classes and objects. How can I launch such big project on Zeppelin.

For some particular requirement, I have to do this......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct and supported way to do this, is to extract an API to your code **compile it as a jar** library, and use Zeppelin's dependency handling [see interpreter settings] to **add the jar** of your existing project to Zeppelin. Then you can call the complex methods of your project from within Zeppelin, using compact and notebook-compatible bits of code.